# How to create acknowledgements in the report class?

Tags: sectioning, abstract

I'm using LaTeX and like to create an acknowledgement section using the `report` class such that is looks like the abstract and comes after it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I went with:

```
\begin{abstract}
 This is cool paper about vuvuzelas.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 Thanks Mum!
\end{abstract}
```

This way both look similar and good.

Comment: Good answer. Better to make a new environment, though :-)

Comment: @WillRobertson How can one make such a new environment?

Comment: @Mathuser Something like `\newenvironment{acknowledgements} {\renewcommand\abstractname{Acknowledgements}\begin{abstract}} {\end{abstract}}`

Comment: This answer also puts them in the table of contents. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25799/78560

Answer (score 37):

```
\section*{Acknowledgements}
Thanks Mum.
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that earlier then got called away from my computer.  Some people (not I) would say that you should instead use `\section*{Acknowledgments}`.

Comment: I bet the same people would also spell it "mom" instead.

Comment: I'd print it on aluminum foil.