# How can I add abstract and acknowledgement pages into the table of contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, abstract

I followed Mike's solution from my first question:

[Roman numeral page numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/roman-numeral-page-numbering/25794#25794)

My next question is how to add entries (for the abstract and acknowledgements pages) into the table of contents.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that the abstract and acknowledgement contents is typeset using a `\chapter*{...}`, you could do the following:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}%
...
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}%
...
```

This will add a chapter-level (`chapter`) entry to the table of contents (`toc`) without a chapter number (`\numberline{}`).

Comment: what do i do if i am adding abstract.tex to my main thesis.tex file ? in this case how do i add page numbering in roman ?

Comment: @Hirak: Either `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}` or `\pagenumbering{roman}`. The latter also resets the page counter. However, I'm not sure whether this is what you're asking about.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer and technically correct, the hyperlinks in the TOC will not go to the correct location without `\phantomsection`. See Stefan's answer for a complete solution.

Comment: @gwg: Correct, if you're using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (which there is no mention of in the OP).

Answer (score 15):

While you can manually add an entry to the TOC by `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline`, the order of commands can be important, especially

- if you use `hyperref`, to get the hyperlink above the heading, not below
- or if you add a section to the TOC, which is done by a macro but several pages long, such as by `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` or `\bibliography`. A wrong order would add the **last** page to the TOC

So

- use `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline` before `\chapter*` of `\listof...`
- ensure the required page break before `\addtocontents` or `\addcontentsline`
- for hyperref, add an anchor for the target

  ```
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  ```

If you need that several times, you could define a macro for it.

Regarding the commands:

- `\cleardoublepage` ends the page, prints out remaining floats if necessary, and ensures that the following text starts on a right hand page, as chapters in books commonly do, if in twoside mode. `\clearpage`, in contrast, would start the new page on a left or a right side.
- `\phantomsection` is a command of the `hyperref` package, which creates an anchor at this location, similar to `\hypertarge`, which can be referred to - `\addcontentsline` does it implicitely. Without `\phantomsection`, `\addcontentsline` would refer to the previous anchor which could be undesired.

The package [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) makes putting commonly added chapters/sections (bibliography, TOC, index) to the TOC easier. It's integrated in the `memoir` class, while KOMA-Script classes support this purpose by class options such as `bibliography=totoc`.

Comment: You've used `\cleardoublepage`, `\phantomsection` - could you be more specific about those two ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I updated my answer and explained the commands.

Comment: Thank you, it's educative piece of tex code for learning latex :).

Answer (score 7):

Instead of tinkering with `\cleardoublepage`, `\phantomsection`, and `\addcontentsline`, I suggest to

- use `\chapter` (the non-starred version) also for the Abstract and Acknowledgements,
- set the `secnumdepth` counter to -2 (i.e., no sectioning level is numbered) before the Abstract,
- reset`secnumdepth` to 2 (default for the `report` class) before the first proper chapter.

Works also with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}% default for "report" is 2

\chapter{Abstract}

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

[image]