# How can I add abstract to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract

I believe it is correct to add the abstract to my TOC but I don't know how. [This Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/how-can-i-add-abstract-and-acknowledgement-pages-into-the-table-of-contents) talking about adding the abstract chapter to the TOC. I'm using Lyx and if I output to .tex file this is what I see.

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{My Title}


\author{My Name}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}
\begin{abstract} %% This isn't a chapter!
```

My Abstract isn't a chapter.

---

Abstract is created with `begin{abstract}` unlike in questions I **LINKED** to and have been marked as a duplicate. In that example abstract is a chapter.
Does this affect the correct use of getting my Abstract into the TOC?

---

> Assuming that the abstract and acknowledgement contents is typeset using a \chapter*{...},

Well it isn't, So what do I do in my case?

Comment: Welcome to the site! `\addcontentsline` will be your friend here :) for example, `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think its a bit silly that I have been linked to the question, I had already posted in my own question. So I exchange Chapter with section? because my abstract isn't labeled as a chapter is is identified by `begin{Abstract}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls), the `abstract` environment is set using within a `titlepage`, which defaults to putting the content on its own page. So you have to insert the ToC-writing piece using some patching (supported via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\titlepage}{\titlepage% Insert ToC-writing after starting a titlepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}}{}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\title{My Title}

\author{My Name}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

I've written the ToC-entry as a `chapter`, just so the formatting seems consistent

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

However, that can be changed to whatever you like.

---

Another way would be to write the ToC-entry within the `abstract` environment - this ensures that it falls on the same page as the Abstract:

```
\begin{abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  ...
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: I'm gonna have to read this a couple a times, I'll come back to this in bit. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the `\addcontentsline` command. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 11):

As abstract is neither a chapter nor a section so for **abstract** you should use

> \begin{abstract}....\end{abstract}

as shown below:

```
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{abstract}

abstract content here
\end{abstract}
```

Line below is used to show abstract in list of contents:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{abstract}
```