# Centering Abstract title and adding it to table of contents in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to add the abstract to my document in LaTeX and I have two issues:

1. Abstract title not in center
2. Abstract not being added in the toc.

Is there any way to do both? There are a lot of solutions that do only one of the above but not both. Also, I wouldn't want the abstract to be a separate chapter.

I have tried using below in the main.tex

```
\begin{abstract}
    Here goes the body of the abstract
\end{abstract}
```

This keeps the abstract title itself to the left.

The second attempt I created a new file and called this in the main.tex:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}
\phantomsection
\end{center}
\begin{abstract}
    Here goes the body of the abstract
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
```

This does add it to the table of contents but the Abstract title is again to the left.
is there any way I could achieve centralizing the abstract title and adding it to the table of contents without making it a chapter? Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the entire class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, english, singlespacing,alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing,consistentlayout,]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    Body of the content
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

Comment: To be able to help you, you'll have to be a bit more specific: which `documentclass` are you using, what have you already tried etc. I suppose in your case a so-called minimal working example would be helpful, i.e. a compilable version of your code containing only the relevant parts including the `documentclass`, related packages and some lines of text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add abstract to table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165018/how-can-i-add-abstract-to-table-of-contents)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! From the link I gave you can try the answer given by @Taimoor at the end. You have to compile twice for the content to actually update.. In addition, the `report` class does make the abstract appear in the center.

Comment: Yes i tried his solution. Abstract is in toc but still not in the center besides my document class is {MasterDoctoralthesis} I guess this is causing the issue. Not sure how to proceed

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual#i-want-to-change-the-layout-of-predefined-abstractdeclarationetc-page