# Unable to match the margin in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have used this code from [how-can-i-add-abstract-and-acknowledgement-pages-into-the-table-of-contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25798/how-can-i-add-abstract-and-acknowledgement-pages-into-the-table-of-contents) to add abstract and acknowledgement. However, I am not able to match the chapter titles with the existing margin format of other chapter titles.

Like shown in the picture!
[image: Screenshot]

My code after title page and before introduction chapter is given as;

```
\pagenumbering{roman} 
%\shipout\null
%\stepcounter{page}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgement}%
\lipsum
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}%
\lipsum

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Please let me know how to correct the margin in TOC. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a bit more of dummy content using the `duckuments` package. You get the correct alignment if you drop the `\numberline{}` in the last `\addcontentsline` argument.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement}%
\blindduck
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}%
\blindduck

\duckument

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image]